# Creating a multi-dimensional json based on mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, json

Earlier, I used to encode the result set (one dimensional) into json. Now, I need to create a multi-dimensional json data structure based on multiple tables. I never done this and I need some help.

My tables:

- users (1 to many)
- phones (many to 1)
- addresses (many to 1)
- names (many to 1)

I need to develop JSON response that has this structure for each row:

- user_id: user_id
- phones: phone1, phone2, phone3, etc.
- addresses: address1, address2, address3, etc.
- names: name1, name2, name3, etc.

How should I do it?

For example, I am thinking that I can create 3 queries for each table (phones, addresses, names) and return a data set for each table and then encode each result set into json. Now my questions: Will it be a correct way of doing this? How do I add each child json into my parent json?

```
$userJson = json_encode($user_id_resultSet);
$phonesJson = json_encode($phones_resultSet);
$addressesJson = json_encode($addresses_resultSet);
$namesJson = json_encode($names_resultSet);
//how do I combine them into one row?
```

Comment: Combine them before you encode the data into JSON

Comment: are you talking about combining the results sets (doing `array_merge`) or creating some sort of query that returns one result set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$combined = array(
  "user" => $user_id_resultSet,
  "phones" => $phones_resultSet,
  "addresses" => $addresses_resultSet,
  "names" => $names_resultSet
);

echo json_encode($combined, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); // just for neat output.
```

Comment: that is amazing. What about dong it in the loop? When I have multiple users (so there should be multiple rows?)

Comment: @Andrew - that's just basic array manipulation, give it a go! Try an empty array `$users = array();` and then add new stuff to it with `$users[] = array( ... );`. You can then add `$users` to the combined array sent to the JSON encoder.